# Different ways to wire parallel-series battery pack

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries

I need to wire up a battery pack using 1.5V AA cells in the form of a parallel-series configuration to achieve 4.5V and 9Ah (assuming a single cell gives 3Ah). The first configuration in the image is one way I've seen it recommended online: 3 cells in series to give 4.5V and 3Ah, then 3 of those in parallel to give 4.5V and 9Ah.

I'm wondering if the second diagram in the image also works? Start with 3 cells in parallel to give 1.5V and 9Ah, then wire 3 of those in series to give 4.5V and 9Ah? Is this correct? What's the advantages/disadvantages between the two options (assuming the 2nd works)? 
[image: Two configurations]

Comment: Same same thing thing ....there are no differences unless you want to consider potential failure modes of a cell (open circuit or short circuit) ...then it matters

Comment: 3Wh maybe ?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_battery#Comparison

Comment: I don't know how your comment and link are related. Please explain @TonyStewart.EEsince'75

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346255/series-parallel-aa-batteries-connection/346261#346261

Comment: Jack your value for Ah per cell is far too high considering to final voltage used for 0% SoC will not be valid without matching the same v vs I specs

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I'm still confused on what you're saying. I gave the Ah per cell as a value to make the question complete. Does what you're trying to say affect the clarity of my question? I did say "assume" 3Ah per cell

Comment: 1) provide link to battery specs 2) state your design limits for Vbat, Then compute the array and capacity of the array. it is never the same as suggested unless your test conditions are identical.

Comment: I do appreciate your insights, but how does this relate to the question? I'm not testing my assumption of 3Ah. Either way, I'm using these batteries (http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/l91.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second allows for balancing in each set of three.  The first does not allow for any balancing and is more likely to cause problems with poor batteries stopping the power output prematurely.  Theoretically they are the same though. See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/389464/316131)